# Hibernate search, possible to search special chars?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to find by fullTextQuery exactly word with special chars? Search by luke working good with query, but from fullTextQuery returns no results.

```
new BooleanClause(qBuilder.keyword().wildcard().
onField("field").matching("c++").createQuery(),BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
```

Without wildcard searching for "c" without special chars.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: First off how to you index and in particular analyze the field? Provided 'c++' is indexed as is, then why don't you do a keyword() query. Under the hood this becomes a Lucene TermQuery. Also, '+' is not a special wildcard character in Lucene, so it should not cause any problems in this regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `@Analyzer(impl = WhitespaceAnalyzer.class)` over that field, may solve your problem.